# VirtualBox 6.1 network setup for windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I am trying to set a `CosmosDB Emulator`, I have -

```
MacOS Big Sur 11.2.1
VirtualBox 6.1
ISO Windows 10
```

I tried  both `NatNetwork` and `Bridge Connection` network setup but my VM is not showing any connection (Internet Connection).

How can I setup a network connection from my host machine to VM so I can access `Emulator` from my MacOS locally.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing virtual box extensions in your host machine.

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing some sources or documentation pointing out your solution.